# Comparar chars entre Strings

Tags: java, string

Quisiera saber como comparar los chars de los strings para saber cuantos char coinciden independientemente de su posicion. Estoy haciendo esto pero se me va de las manos, no me sale la longitud que debería.

```
        /* Panel mostrará los caracteres de "frase" que coincidan con   
        "intentos". Los que no coincidan los mostrará con un guion:"-" */                 
        String panel = "";

        String intentos = "String intentos";
        String frase = "Esto es una frase";

        for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < frase.length(); j++)
            {
                if (j!=i && intentos.charAt(j) == frase.charAt(i))
                {
                    panel+=frase.charAt(i);
                }
                else 
                {
                    panel+="-";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: que es intentos ?  que es frase?  agrega esa información por favor.

Comment: Cual es el resultado que esperas en tu ejemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo sería utilizando un arreglo de caracteres, que inicialmente se llena con guiones y sólo si coincide una de las letras de intentos con una de frase es reemplazada en la posición que la misma se encuentre en frase.

También corrijo un error en los ciclos for que los dos recorrían hasta la longitud de frase, provocando que en algún punto intentara buscar caracteres fuera de la longitud de intentos.

```
    String intentos = "String intentos";
    String frase = "Esto es una frase";
    char panel[] = new char[frase.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
        panel[i] = '-';
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < intentos.length(); j++) {
            if (intentos.toLowerCase().charAt(j) == frase.toLowerCase().charAt(i)) {
                panel[i] = frase.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(panel[i]);
    }
```